# Allocating memory for a 3D array

Tags: c, memory, multidimensional-array, malloc

I have the array : `char game[10][10][3]`, and I want to allocate memory for the [10][10] , how should I do it?
I thought in something like `char **game[3]`, but when I do some malloc, it says that I need to inicialize the array.

Comment: What is wrong with `char game[10][10][3];`? Why do you need to allocate it dynamically?

Comment: "it says that I need to inicialize the array." --> what is "it".

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to allocate:

```
 typedef char game_board[10][10][3];

 game_board* board = malloc(sizeof(game_board));
```

Though honestly just using it without pointers will be a lot less messy.

Remember that `char **game[3]` is a pointer *to a pointer* to an array of size 3. Note the intermediate pointer. In the original definition it's an array of 10 array of 10 arrays of length 3. There is *no pointers* in this structure. While both forms can be referenced like `game[x][y][z]` that is only because of how C has made the syntax identical. It's not a reflection on the actual structure involved.

Comment: or `... board = malloc(sizeof *board);`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica That's what the cool kids do and I'm not sure I'm that cool.